# How to add custom FTL pages in Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak, freemarker, keycloak-services

I want to add a custom FTL-page to the existing Keycloak pages.
Let's call it 'special-number.ftl' that contains a form where you can enter a number and send it to the backend. The submit button should trigger custom java code that I wrote.
How do I do this? How do I trigger a custom FTL-page to be shown and trigger some code I wrote with a click on the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write a Keycloak extension and implement a custom `RealmResourceProvider`:

To do so start with a `RealmResourceProviderFactory`

```
public class CustomRealmResourceProviderFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

    public static final String ID = "my-custom-pages";

    @Override
    public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return new CustomRealmResourceProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

And the according `RealmResourceProvider`:

```
public class CustomRealmResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {



    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("mypage")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getSuccessPage() {
        LoginFormsProvider forms = keycloakSession.getProvider(LoginFormsProvider.class);
        return forms.createForm("my-form-template.ftl");
    }


}
```

Create the freemarker template `theme-resources/templates/my-form-template.ftl`

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayInfo=true; section>
    <#if section = "header">
        ${msg("welcome")}
    <#elseif section = "form">
     CONTENT
    </#if>
</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

Then add the path of the `CustomRealmResourceProviderFactory` to the following file in you project:
`META-INF/services/org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory`

Build and add as provider to your keycloak setup.
Your endpoints will be available at:
`/realms/{realmName}/{RealmResourceProviderId}/{path}`

In this example:
`/realms/{realmName}/my-custom-pages/mypage`

For more information see: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have created a page in your local, then run the following command from a cli:

```
docker cp special-number.ftl containerId:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/account
```

ContainerId will be your docker container id.
In the above example, it is going to the base themes, you can change it to wherever you want it to go.

Comment: Sure that adds the .ftl file. But how to get it triggered and where to put the Java code that needs to call it and handle whatever form submission that comes afterwards...

Comment: This is really a very bad answer which doesn't tell anything about what to expect exactly.