# Add custom html page to keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Is it possible to add custom HTML page to keycloak? I have a requirement where I should add html page let's name it as `custom-page.html` and access that page like `mydomain.org/auth/custom-page.html`.

Comment: I created custom API which returns HTML page as a response. But accessing it directly through browser returns HTTP 401. Need to add authenticate when token is not available for API

Comment: I provided an answer for this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76573950/8752286